# comment box facebook

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hi am developing facebook comment box on my web site.. if i click that login button below on the comment box in this sense it will go through facebook page..instant of it that login should be go to my website page..itz for feedback am devoloping... this is example site http://twitter.com/exclusivetaxi .. kindly visit that link and solve my problem..

plz......

thanks 
gowtham